# how to fix NoReverseMatch django/python

Tags: python, django

I want to add a link to my html file:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary">Read</a>
```

views.py

```
def detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = HomeData.objects.get(
        date__year=year,
        date__month=month,
        date__day=day,
        slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'main/articles/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py in app 'main'

```
app_name='main'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<slug:post>/', views.detail, name='DETAIL'),
]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
    path('', include('main.urls', namespace='main')),
]
```

error

```
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'articles_detail' not found. 'articles_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: D:\django\postsSite\myEnv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 698, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  D:\django\postsSite\myEnv\Scripts\python.exe
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you share the view/model/template where you use `reverse`/`redirect`/`{% url ... %}` for `articles_detail`?

Comment: The only view I see defined with a URL is named `'DETAIL'`; no `'articles_detail'`. Perhaps use that name?